# Item already owned error on buying a previously refunded purchase

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I am testing the refund workflow for my in-app purchases. I am verifying the purchase receipt using the Google Play Developer API https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get. If a user has asked for a refund of the purchase, this API returns the `purchaseState` as `1` which is correct. At that point, I remove the purchase from my app and the user can no longer avail the benefits of the in-app purchase. But now if a user wants to buy the in-app purchase again, I get the `Item already owned` error while buying it.

I am not sure how to allow the user to buy the in-app purchase again. I can consume the item once the purchase is reported as canceled in which case I don't get the `Item already owned` error but I don't think that would be the correct thing to do though.

Please let me know how to handle this use-case.